# How to assign a attribute value to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Is it possible to use button attribute as a variable name of an array in JavaScript? I tried to do it as follows but it returns syntax error.

```
var $(this).attr("value") = [];
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `var attrvalue = $(this).attr("value")` ?

Comment: use an object and define it as object property..... `var obj = {}; obj[$(this).attr("value")] = [];` ..... or you can initialize it as global variable `window[$(this).attr("value")] = [];`

Comment: var attrValue = $(element).attr("attr key");

Comment: @guradio I want to use `$(this).attr("value")` as variable name.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Your answer is correct. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttonValueAttribute = $(this).attr('value');
```

Comment: I want to use $(this).attr("value") as variable name.

Comment: That is not possible - you cannot use certain characters in variable names, like the `.`